# time complexity of specific nested loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

Why is the time complexity of this function is T(n) = O(n) and not T(n) = O(n*log(n))? I think the answer to this question lies inside the first loop. isn't the time complexity of the first loop is log(n)?

```
void f(int n) {
    for( ; n>0; n/=2 ){
       int i;
       for (i=0; i<n; i++)
         printf("Hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: The mistake lies in naively multiplying the individual complexities of the two loops together -- note that `n` changes after every execution of the outer loop. Hint: *geometric series*.

Comment: Well, if you sum up the infinite series n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 ..., you end up with 2n.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the first loop changes the value of `n`. It divides `n` by `2` in each iteration which show that first loop runs `log(n)` step. We can rewrite it in this way: `for (int k = 1; k <= n; k *= 2)`. Second loop runs upto `k`. So we have

[image]